# Is it possible to overlay ungeoreferenced raster images in the QGIS Desktop Browser?

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing

I work for a company that produces Mining Investigation reports for property in the South West of England and I have spent the last 12 months digitising abandoned mine plans, geological survey, old ordnance survey maps etc onto a custom built GIS in QGIS. However, many of archive and analogue maps are extremely difficult to fit using a georeferencing tool, be it ARC or QGIS.

Therefore, it would be a lifesaver and an invaluable tool to be able to import and overlay ungeoreferenced raster images into the QGIS Desktop and be able to manipulate them over layers already in the browser, almost like a lightbox.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free web-based georeferencing tool designed for old inaccurate maps here:

http://warp.worldmap.harvard.edu/

Comment: This looks like a great bit of kit, but what I am really interested in is being able to overlay raster images directly into the QGIS browser, to produce a really accurate localised fit.

Comment: You can export a WMS layer of the image you are georeferencing from WARP. So you could perhaps display the WMS layer in QGIS while you keep moving the control points around in WARP (it sometimes takes a few minutes to update depending on the image size) and checking in QGIS to see how you are doing. You can then export a GeoTiff once you are happy with the results. Thats the best I can think of. It doesnt allow you to move the control points around directly in QGIS, but you would still be able to see how you are progressing.

Answer (score 1):

I use frequently the Freehand raster georeferencer plugin for QGIS, this is an interactive tool where you load an image overlay with options to move scale and rotate.